# Pass --autosquash to git pull --rebase=interactive

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

When doing `git pull --rebase=interactive`, can I somehow pass the `--autosquash` flag like I can for a "normal" `git rebase -i`?

Comment: Try `git -c rebase.autosquash=true pull --rebase=interactive` i.e. [temporary (one-time)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt) set [config value](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rebaseautoSquash).

Comment: @phd That looks like it should be an answer, so that it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks. I didn't try it myself. Let's wait for the topicstarter to confirm it works.